# Should I write off my time invested in developing a business

Tags: taxes, losses

Last year was my first year in business.  I spent a good chuck of time developing my business plan, designing the company website, and developing policies and procedures for my employees.  I'm about 65% done with everything needed before actually getting clients.

I will be calming a loss this year on my business taxes.  The business is a registered LLC and I am the only member (thus pass-through taxes).  Should (and can) I write off my time spend on the business as a loss as well?  If so, how would I determine the pay rate and document such activity legally?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Related: [Can I write off time I spent working on my business?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22420/can-i-write-off-time-i-spent-working-on-my-business)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Unless you actually laid out cash for it, you can't write it off.

Comment: And obviously if you did pay yourself, you'll have to pay income tax on your earnings.